# Trying to make my wampsever so it will have access to the public

Tags: wamp, wampserver

So i am pretty new to WampServer or local working environment in general.

I am trying to making so my people outside my network(lan) will be able to access my www folder.

So far i did the following:

- Installed wamp.
- Put the server online
- Edited httpd.conf and set `<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">` to `Allow from all`.

It doesn't seem to work.

I read something about port forwarding, however i have no access to my router at all. is there anything else that might effect this ?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your network firewall needs to allow outside connections. You need port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot port forward your router then you cannot let people into your server.

A router will normally reject any access to any port that has not been initiated by an internal ip address. Normal router operation will block people trying to hack your internal systems.

Port forwarding the router says to the router, if you get accessed from outside (i.e. the internet) on port 80, forward that request to a specific ip address inside your local(home) network. That ip should be the PC running WAMP. If you cannot set your router up in this way you are scuppered.